# How linux device drivers are loaded?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Can anyone explain me in simple terms the following thing.
How Linux drivers are loaded into kernel space?
Which functions are exported, after drivers being loaded?
How driver functions are called?

Comment: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Module-HOWTO/ read this doc

Comment: There's [entire books](http://www.oreilly.com/openbook/linuxdrive3/book/) written about Linux drivers, so what specific issue are you having?

Comment: Wrong forum. Try http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Read this [article](http://haifux.org/lectures/86-sil/kernel-modules-drivers/kernel-modules-drivers.html).

Answer (score 2):

Normally you will use `insmod` or `modprobe` userspace application to load module (and possibly its dependencies in case of the 2nd one). Both of them do the same under the hood to actually load single module - they read the file into memory and use `init_module` system call, providing address of memory where this module was loaded. This call tells kernel that module should be loaded.

Now kernel modules are actually ELF files and are not much different from shared libraries used in userspace. The kernel has an equivalent of shared library linker, that will parse those files, get a list of symbols that are provided by it, updating the list of functions known to kernel. It will also check if all the symbols that this module needs are already in the kernel and do proper relocations. One of the last thing that it will do is to call initialization function in the module.

Note that you cannot compile the kernel that will directly call any function that is provided by module. Similarly, you can call any function provided by a module in another module before loading the first one. Kernel will refuse to load any module with symbols that are not known. Most of the modules will, however, register its functions as some kind of callbacks that can be called indirectly.

Comment: and `modprobe` to load a module and automatically load its dependent modules.